# Android Studio - ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 not found?

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, android-instrumentation

I am trying to unit test my MainActivty. My project cannot find ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and android.test package. I changed the target SDK to 27 to see if that resolves that problem but to no avail.
This is how my gradle looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "aziz.ai.gpsspeedometer"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs 'src\\main\\java', 'src\\main\\java\\common'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 [is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2) on API level 24
put compileSdkVersion 23 or upgrade the test class to the new test classes